# Obtener credenciales en AWS CLI

Tags: webservice, funciones, servidor, function, aws

estoy tratando de obtener las credenciales de AWS CLI pero me genera un error, al ingresar el siguiente comando: `serverless config credentials --provider aws --key BxxxxxxxxkeyxxxxxG --secret nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8` con sus respectivas llaves, me genera el siguiente mensaje:

*Serverless: Setting up AWS...*
*Serverless: Failed! ~/.aws/credentials already has a "default" profile. Use the overwrite flag ("-o" or "--overwrite") to force the update*

ya realicé la respectiva configuración con `aws configure`, le ingresé las llaves del usuario y su región, pero cuando realizo el `serverless config...` me sale el mismo error, entonces le agregue al comando el --overwrite y --profile nombre_usuario, me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
*Serverless: Setting up AWS...*

---

Gracias por su tiempo, y por la respuesta oportuna, feliz día.

Comment: Las credenciales las estás cargando en tu máquina o en una instancia EC2?

Comment: Las estoy cargando en mi máquina con la terminal de windows, tambien intenté con el nodejs command prompt

Answer (score 0):

el último mensaje lo que quiere decir es que efectivamente sobrescribió el perfil "Default" con las credenciales que usted proporcionó.

Puede chequearlo en el archivo ubicado en tu carpeta de usuario en la siguiente ruta **.aws/credentials**.

Otra alternativas es que ejecute el comando `aws configure list` y de esta manera listar todos los perfiles configurados en su máquina, sólo podrá ver las última 4 letras de las credenciales.

Por otro lado para tener mayor autonomía en cada proyecto serverless si desarrollas para diferentes cuentas, puedes agregar el parametro '--profile NUEVO_NOMBRE_PROFILE' de esta manera tendrá un profile para cada cuenta con sus repectiva credenciales, sólo debe asegurarse que en cada ejecución del comando 'serverless' agregue al final el parametro '--profile NUEVO_NOMBRE_PROFILE'.

Answer (score 0):

Tranquilo, ya lo tienes configurado. Si lo que quieres es desplegar con el perfil que ya tienes seteado por default, cuando ejecutes sls deploy se utilizara el perfil por defecto. Si quieres crear otro perfil los puedes hacer como lo estas haciendo pero añadiendo la opcion profile para indicarle el nombre del nuevo perfil, si el perfil ya existe tendras que añadir la opcion de -o para sobreescribirlo. Para usarlo cuando hacer el sls deploy puedes hacerlo cuando ejecute el comando, solo tienes que añadir sls deploy --aws-profil <NOMBRE_PERFIL> y tambien puedes seleccionar el perfil desde el serverless.yml.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).